# Select2 no muesta en el html el valor extraido de la base de datos para editarlo en un modal

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, select2

tengo el siguiente problema, estoy intentado editar la informacion de un usuario mediante un modal utilizando ajax, todo funciona muy bien la peticion ajax me devuelve un objeto listo para poder quemar esos datos en el html pero el problema radica en el select2 no me esta mostrando el valor a editar en el html pero cuando inspeciono el select el Id junto con el nombre si estan en dicho select, cabe destacar inicializo el select2 mediante un document ready function

Este es mi codigo html

```
<div class="input-group mb-3">
    <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-university"></i></span>
    </div>
    <select class="form-control selectedituser" name="carrerauseredit">
        <option id="carrerauseredit"></option>
     </select>
</div>
```

y este es mi codigo js donde inicializo el select2 y tambien la funcion que realiza la peticion ajax

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.selectedituser').select2({
    placeholder: 'Selecione el programa de estudio del Usuario',
    theme: 'bootstrap4'
})});
```

y esta es la forma en que estoy tratando de quemar los datos en el select

```
var datoscarrera = new FormData();
        datoscarrera.append("idcarrera", respuesta["Id_carrera"]); 
        $.ajax({
            url: 'ajax/carreras.php',
            method: 'POST',
            data: datoscarrera,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (respuesta1) {
                console.log(respuesta1);
                $("#carrerauseredit").val(respuesta1["Id_carrera"]);
                $("#carrerauseredit").html(respuesta1["Nombre"]);
                
            }
        });
```

realizado lo anterior el select me aparece completamente en blanco me lo muestra sin resultados pero al inspecionar el elemento efectivamente ahi esta la informacion que necesito mostrar en el html.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

realice las pruebas con las lineas de codigo proporcionadas y el resultado fue el siguiente. No logro resolver este detalle

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Hay una clase que dice `select2-hidden-accessible` y un `atributo` llamado `aria-hidden = true`, alguno de estos dos impide la visualización de lo que mandas a tu `select`.

Intenta poner esto después del cierre del `ajax`:

```
$(".selectedituser").toggleClass("select2-hidden-accessible");//retira la clase
$(".selectedituser").removeAttr("aria-hidden");//retira el atributo
```

Ya dependiendo del que sea el que lo impide, lo usas.

Comment: Los atributos `aria` tienen que ver con accesibilidad, `aria-hidden` en concreto, es para ocultar (o mostrar) un elemento de la API de accesibilidad. Por ejemplo, para que los programas que leen la pantalla, se salten ese elemento y no lo lean.

Comment: Un saludo nuevamente @valle50 te comento que retirando la clase con esta linea del codigo obtengo el efecto que mostre en la repuesta anterior en la parte superior, si retiro el atributo no tengo efecto alguno el punto es que impelemente el codigo tanto en el success del ajax como fuera del ajax y obtuve el mismo resultado, saludos

Answer (score 0):

Encontraste la solucion? estoy con el mismo porblema, ya he intentado de muchas maneras pero no doy con la solucion. :/

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]: haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio. Si aún sigues sin encontrar la solución, [haz una nueva pregunta](/questions/ask), leyendo [ask]. La sección de respuestas es para las propuestas de solución, no para comentarios del tipo _tengo el mismo problema_. Lee [answer].

Comment: No @Isaac C.F. no utilicé el plugin en la seccion editar lo hicen con el selec normal de boostrap

Comment: @JersonJosuéRodriguez okey, yo tenia el mismo problema y lo solucioné, la manera en que lo hice fue extrayendo los datos y pasarlos a un array y asi se los pase al select2 para que los cargara automaticamente en el option y asi tener acceso al value